# eclipse cdt command line input

Tags: eclipse, command-line, arguments, eclipse-cdt

I'm new to eclipse cdt. I'm wondering how can i add command line argument (e.g.-lm) for compiling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "correct" way is probably to include these parameters in your Makefile.

But if you're invoking the compiler manually, you should be able to set arguments by right-clicking on the project, selecting "Properties", choosing the "C/C++ Build" entry on the menu at the left, and editing the "Build command" text field.

Depending on the system you're in, you could potentially also choose the 'Build Variables' subentry under "C/C++ Build" and set them in CFLAGS/CPPFLAGS. Not every setup takes those into account, though.

Answer (score 2):

Debug-> Debug-Configurations. Select Arguments

Answer (score 1):

-lm include the math library. This is a linker parameters.

Project Proprerties -> C/C++ build -> Settings -> GCC Linker -> Libraries -> "add the library" m

Comment: Voting this up to counter downvote, because although late and very brief, it is actually the most correct answer. It's a linker flag that the OP needs, and adding it to the place @Benoch mentions, will cause the -l<somelibrary> to be included in the build command and link to the required library. The accepted answer is in the vicinity, but this is exactly where to place it. For another example, I needed libexif in a project, so adding "exif" to the libraries section, added -lexif to the build command.