# Passing arguments to a C++ program in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I have a C++ program written using `Eclipse CDT`. This program needs arguments to be passed to it. How can I do that using `Eclipse CDT`?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [eclipse cdt command line input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203533/eclipse-cdt-command-line-input)

Comment: The link above is actually not related, my bad. I was too hasty there.

Comment: @user588855 - Did you try my answer? Please mark it as the solution if it works for you.

Comment: @Dennis. I'm having a problem with running Eclipse. But, if you are SURE your solution works, I will mark it as a solution. Does it work?

Comment: @user588855 Yeah I am sure that this works. Would appreciate it if you could mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You'll find the option under "Run->Run Configurations".
Just enter the options here as normal and hit "Run".

[image: Arguments Input in Eclipse]