# final link failed: Invalid argument when including windows.h

Tags: c++, windows, linker, g++, mingw

I have set up MinGW and Eclipse with CDT for C++ developing on Windows. Everything works great until I `#include <windows.h>`. As soon as I do that, I get the linker error message `c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid argument` whereby the path at the beginning resolves to `C:/MinGW/mingw32/bin/ld.exe`.

I have no idea what the error message tries to tell me... so please help me to decrypt it.

Comment: Is it full error message? (Also path should be ok, while it looks crazy.)

Comment: @Lol4t0 Yes, it is the full error message except of the following `collect2: ld returned 1 exit status` and `C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe: *** [Test-Project] Error 1` but I don't think they are relevant in any case.

Comment: Looks like some internal error for me. Make sure your compiler is not broken, try rebuilding project...

Comment: @Lol4t0 You were right, reinstalling the compiler solved the problem. This means I could have been searching forever to find the failure >.> Thank you very much for saving me from that disaster :D

Comment: @Lol4t0 If you don't post it as answer, I'll do it myself.

Comment: "Your compiler is broken. Reinstall it" doesn't look like a good SO answer, really! :)

Comment: Actually, question should be closed or removed as too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I actually don't agree to Lol4t0's opinion that this is too localized here is the ugly answer: Reinstalling G++ solved the problem.

I think the problem also could have been that I maybe forgot to install one of the parts listed [here](http://yongshin.blogspot.de/2005/11/how-to-use-cdt-and-mingw-for-eclipse.html) (where I got it from) for the first time... but now I recognize the link is completely deprecated (2005). So one should use another anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are missing one of the linking parameters on the command line.

E.g., you might want to add the `-lgdi32 -lkernel32 -luser32` if you use any of WinAPI functions declared in `<windows.h>`

Since you are getting errors in Eclipse, add these libraries (gdi32, kernel32, user32) here:

> Project Proprerties -> C/C++ build -> Settings -> GCC Linker -> Libraries -> "add the library"

(this is taken from [eclipse cdt command line input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203533/eclipse-cdt-command-line-input))