# Qt Compile error at make

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator, mingw32

I've got stuck compiling a program which gets to the end and then fails. I'm not sure what is missing. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

```
g++ -Wl, -Wl,--large-address-aware -Wl,-s -mthreads -Wl,-subsystem,windows -o release/nutcoin-qt.exe object_script.nutcoin-qt.Release  -L'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/mingw/lib' -lmingwthrd -lmingw32 -lqtmain build/nutcoin-qt_res.o -lqrencode -lminiupnpc -liphlpapi E:/GitHub/nutcoin/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a E:/GitHub/nutcoin/src/leveldb/libmemenv.a -lshlwapi -lssl -lcrypto -ldb_cxx -lws2_32 -lmswsock -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lgdi32 -lboost_system-mgw44-mt-s-1_53 -lboost_filesystem-mgw44-mt-s-1_53 -lboost_program_options-mgw44-mt-s-1_53 -lboost_thread-mgw44-mt-s-1_53 -lboost_chrono-mgw44-mt-s-1_53 -lQtGui4 -lQtNetwork4 -lQtCore4 
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `E:/GitHub/nutcoin-qt-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Release'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: : No such file: Invalid argument
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [release/nutcoin-qt.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe: *** [release] Error 2
17:16:39: The process "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project nutcoin-qt (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

Comment: Similar problem.. see if this fixes your issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/10429085/2648826

Comment: Also, why are you using that old mingw?

Answer (score -1):

Because of the following error output:

> mingw32/bin/ld.exe: : No such file: Invalid argument

I suggest checking that all used files in this command line are presented at the disc:

```
build/nutcoin-qt_res.o
E:/GitHub/nutcoin/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a
E:/GitHub/nutcoin/src/leveldb/libmemenv.a
```

and so on...

and the best solution - do NOT use this old mingw! Personally I had a lot headache with it...

Comment: This should have been a comment, but even that has already been made by Digital_Reality. That was useful as a comment, hence my upvote for that. This is not an answer. Also, referring to the old mingw is not a solution for the issue either, hence my comment a few hours ago, not an answer. :)

Comment: Laszlo Papp, Digital_Reality referenced issue with completely another MinGW error code in output.